# Is there a way to position the NavMesh collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to reposition the NavMesh Collider? The only option I'm seeing is BaseOffset but that only repositions vertically.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ended up finding a way to correct this for models that are not centered correctly when you import them. In the ProBuilder Menu select the model. Then select Freeze Transform. Reposition your model and then in the ProBuilder Menu click Center Pivot.

Now it's positioned correctly in the game world to sit right in side of the Agent Collider.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Empty Game Object and add NavMeshAgent component.
Then put your player Object on this Empty Game Object (it will be the parent of your player).

You can now move de player collider independently of the NavMesh collider.

You can also do the reverse to move the NavMesh collider independently of the player collider.

I don't really know if that answers your question but at least I hope it can help you ! ^^'

Comment: That is smart and will work. I was hoping for a less hackish way to reposition it.

Comment: Sorry but you can't simply do this using code. Don't work hard, work smart !

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended finding a fix.

Comment: Can you share your solution please ? It can help people who have the same problem as you.